# The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, char[])

Tags: java, android, char, sharedpreferences, long-integer

I'm getting an error stating: The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, char[])

...and I'm not sure why the issue is occuring or how I can correct it.

I was thinking I could use:

```
editor.putLong("0", data);
```

But that simply results in:

The method putLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, char[])

Error occurs on the line:

editor.putLong("0", data);

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";

        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

             Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);


                SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("0", data);
                editor.commit(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is `char[]`  ,your method signature receives a String , just put `String.valueOf(data)`.

```
editor.putString("0", String.valueOf(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a char array into a method that requires a string. Try doing this:

```
editor.putString("0", new String(data));
```